# how to make `mvn package` aware that it has already built the target

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

In a makefile, I can easily do something like

```
${target}: ${sources}
    mvn package
```

Where I have `${target}` the generated jar file, and `${sources}` all the java files and the `pom.xml`. With this makefile, the target will not be be rebuilt unless one of the sources is changed since the last build of the target. The result is

```
$> make target/demo-0.8.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
make: 'target/demo-0.8.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar' is up to date.
```

But just `mvn package` will *always* run the `maven-assembly-plugin` even though none of the source files has changed.

Question:

Is there a way to make `mvn package` be aware of the source files, similar to how `make` knows this so it'll just say "no need, it's already built."

Comment: What do you mean by `Where I have ${target} the generated jar file, and ${sources} all the java files and the`... can you give a more detailed example of that what you mean here.. best would be an example project on github or alike...

Comment: The `make` command knows that the target only depends on the sources. So if none if the sources has a more recent timestamp than the target, it will not execute the action `mvn package`.
Not coming from a Java/Maven background, I'm looking for the same, sensible behavior in maven, especially since the packaging step is fairly time consuming. `make` will return pretty much instantly if it doesn't have to do anything.

Comment: I know Make/Makefiles very well. The first thing is timestamps are not reliable. The first thing is incremental behaviour is not working in Maven (or better in plugins) because it's an extremely complex part. A number plugins support that (partially) but not all. Apart from that where do you do the `package`.. locally or on build server?

Comment: locally and on a server, on the server it's maven only (via a CI pipeline), but locally I prefer the makefile approach, because it allows me to do something like `make dockerimage`, which depends on the target, and not rebuild the target if I'm just messing with the `Dockerfile`.
I'm happy with the combined makefile + maven approach, but a colleague thinks I'm copying maven functionality.

Comment: Makefile for Java does not make sense. Why do you need to build locally? Can't you run tests via IDE? Creating a docker image is really necessary for local build? The question is what you are doing exactly in your Makefile? Do you have an example project?

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not something makes sense is maybe up to the use case and the developer.
In a system where integration is far more complicated than passing unit tests the only way to gain confidence is by deploying into a test Kubernetes environment.

Anyway thanks for answering my question that the maven packaging plugin is unable to handle this dependency tracking.

Comment: Hm..interesting information which you haven't mentioned... Then local build makes no sense. I would suggest to push your branch to your CI and let the CI deploy to the K8S cluster. So that concludes to the point where the Makefile makes even less sense. What kind of checks/tests you need on K8S which you can't make locally? Unfortunately you don't giving more information so I would be able  to give a more founded answer. If you are on CI incremental build is useless cause every time you build you will get on a different node/pod and your workspace is clean. Only useful caching for local cache.

Comment: Ah btw. can you give exactly how you have defined `${sources}` in your Makefile?